# Table search that works with Laravel Pagination

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, laravel, pagination

I created a table in Laravel with pagination and then added search functionality to it however when I try and search it only searches the current page. How would I fix this so that I can search the information that is on all the pages of the table? I am new to Laravel :)

Table code -

```
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Type to search">
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-field="id">Ident</th>
      <th data-field="name">Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  @foreach ($airports as $airport)
  <tr>
    <td>{{ $airport->ident }}</td>
    <td>{{ $airport->name }}</td>
  </tr>
  @endforeach
  </tbody>
  </table>
  @include('pagination.default', ['paginator' => $airports])
```

Javascript -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $rows = $('#table tr');
$('#search').keyup(function() {
    var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

    $rows.show().filter(function() {
        var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
        return !~text.indexOf(val);
    }).hide();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In laravel if you use pagination it will only load those specific records  set in limit.

```
->paginate(15)
```

When you click the next page button at that time only new set of records will be loaded.So only you search is working for first page alone.

If you want this to work out you can make a ajax call to the controller where the page is loading like this

```php
use App/Airport;

public function getAirportList(Request $request,Airport $airport){

    if ($request->ajax()) {
        $getResult = $airport->where(function($query){
            $query->where('ident',$request->search)
                  ->orWhere('name',$request->search);
        });

        return view('airports', compact('airports'));
    }

    $airports = $airport->paginate(10);
    return view('airports',compact('airports'));
}
```